# Fetching data from React component via Knex

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying a simple `read` operation on my db from a React component. I'm using knex and not sure how to make the call properly.

Here is the how I am making the call:

React Component

```
const library = require('../../../library')

 const retrieveAllRecipes = function () {
    library.getAllRecipes().then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp)
    })
  }
```

library.js

```
function getAllRecipes() {
  return db
    .readRecipes()
    .then((result) => {
      return result
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      logError(err)
    })
    .finally(() => {
      db.close()
    })
}
```

Finally db.js

```
function readRecipes(db = connection) {
  return db('recipes').select()
}
```

My current way returns an error:

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../../library which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

I understand the error but when I try and move the relevant files into the `src` directory I get other errors, leading me to assume this isn't the right way to do things. I had previously used a fetch call with ``fetch(`http://localhost:3001/``` but in this instance I wasn't using raw SQL in the express js file which was also problematic so I am trying to move away from that method.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import files outside of src/ by "copying" the outside files with file: as local dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@my-project/outside-dist": "file:./../../../../dist".
}
```

then

```
import {FooComponent} from "@my-project/outside-dist/components";
```

No `eject` or `react-app-rewired` or `other 3rd-party` solution was needed.